# Why method setValue doesn't output same as Browser.msgBox?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Since I could not make .toFixed(2) to work I designed my own piece of code to add desired decimal digits after the "." by simple joining two strings with + sign.

While Browser.msgBox outputs the 2 strings joined correctly as "1.00", 
it seems like getRange.setValue outputs only the first of the 2 strings as "1"  :(

```
function myFunction() {
var ss_calc = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1cFt0DbnpWGHquKk4ijxdKhwkaF8GhumWDWjTpHuSXbQ");
var sheet_calc = ss_calc.getSheetByName("Calcs");      
var ss_source = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1gXeXmiw9EnzQXaiE7H8_zrilE2zyotlSuuIS8X9IxfQ");
var sheet_source = ss_source.getSheetByName("Farmah");  

var decDig = ""; var strDec = ""; var impVal = "";
impVal = sheet_source.getRange(12,7).getValue().toString();
if (JSON.stringify(impVal).indexOf(".")>-1) 
 { if (JSON.stringify(impVal).split(".")[1].length < 2 ) 
  { 
   if (JSON.stringify(impVal).split(".")[1].length < 1) 
    { 
     decDig = "00"; 
    }
   else 
    { 
     decDig = "0"; 
    }
   }
  } 
else 
{ 
 decDig = ".00"; 
}
var strDec = impVal.toString() + decDig.toString();
Browser.msgBox(JSON.stringify(impVal).indexOf(".")+ "\\n" +
           impVal.toString()+ "\\n" +
           decDig+ "\\n" +
           strDec);
sheet_calc.getRange(1,1).setValue(strDec);
}
```

From sheet_calc.getRange(1,1).setValue(strDec); I am expecting to get output "1.00" but I get only "1" :(

What am I missing?

Here are the links to google spreadsheets ( anyone with the link can edit :)

(above code has to be triggered manually by script editor in the first spreadsheet here under):

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cFt0DbnpWGHquKk4ijxdKhwkaF8GhumWDWjTpHuSXbQ/edit?usp=sharing

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gXeXmiw9EnzQXaiE7H8_zrilE2zyotlSuuIS8X9IxfQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanaike provided me the copy paste solution on the front-end. That's why I have marked Thanaike's answer as the best one.
But Ruben provided me very clear explanation of what is happening in the back-end.
That's why I up-woted his answer also.
Thanks to both :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to put the value of `1.00` to a cell "A1".

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? I think that the reason of your issue is that the value by putting by `setValue()` is converted to the number. By this, `1` is shown. In order to put the value as `1.00`, I think that there are 3 patterns. Please select one of them for your situation.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, from your question, the value is put as a string using `setNumberFormat("@")`.

#### From:

```
sheet_calc.getRange(1,1).setValue(strDec);
```

#### To:

```
sheet_calc.getRange(1,1).setNumberFormat("@").setValue(strDec);
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, from your question, the format of cell is set using `setNumberFormat("0.00")`.

#### From:

```
sheet_calc.getRange(1,1).setValue(strDec);
```

#### To:

```
sheet_calc.getRange(1,1).setNumberFormat("0.00").setValue(strDec);
```

### Pattern 3:

In this pattern, from the script of your shared Spreadsheet, When `decDig` is `".00"`, the format is set.

#### From:

```
sheet_calc.getRange(x+6,c).setValue(strDec);
```

#### To:

```
var range = sheet_calc.getRange(x+6,c);
if (decDig) {
  range.setNumberFormat("0.00").setValue(strDec); // or setNumberFormat("@")
} else {
  range.setValue(strDec);
}
```

### Reference:

- [setNumberFormat(numberFormat)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

> From `sheet_calc.getRange(1,1).setValue(strDec);` I am expecting to get output `"1.00"` but I get only `"1"` :(

Google Sheets, as well as other spreadsheet apps, have an automatic data type assignation, so things that look as numbers are converted to Google Sheets number data type, etc.

You could prepend an `'` to force that a value be treated as text or you could set the number format in such way that numbers are displayed with two decimals. The cell formatting could be applied in advance, i.e., by using the Google Sheets UI commands or you could use Apps Script to set the format for you.